# IntelliJ plugin: Navigate from Project View to a file without triggering AutoScrollFromSource?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm writing an IntelliJ IDEA plugin and I am trying to navigate from the project pane to a file without triggering "autoscrollfromsource" function (even if it is turned on).

I tried temporarily disabling autoscrollfromsource (and re-enabling it afterwards) but this attempt was not successful.

In the code below, it seems it takes a moment for the file to load, and by that time autoscrollfromsource is already re-enabled.

```
private void navigateWithoutAutoscrollFromSource(final ProjectViewImpl projectView, BasePsiNode<? extends PsiElement> node) {
    boolean wasAutoScrollFromSource = projectView.isAutoscrollFromSource(PROJECT_PANE);
    if (wasAutoScrollFromSource) {
        projectView.setAutoscrollFromSource(false, PROJECT_PANE);
    }

    // this navigation here should NOT trigger autoscrollfromsource!!
    node.navigate(true);

    if (wasAutoScrollFromSource) {
        ApplicationManager.getApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                projectView.setAutoscrollFromSource(true, PROJECT_PANE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to navigate to my node, without triggering autoscrollfromsource?

Thanks for any pro tips :)

**Update 1**

I trace the code to the openapi class `OpenFileDescriptor`, here:

```
public void navigate(boolean requestFocus) {
    if (!canNavigate()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Navigation is not possible with null project");
    }

    if (!myFile.isDirectory() && navigateInEditor(myProject, requestFocus)) return;

    navigateInProjectView();
}
```

Basically, I would like to be able to execute this `navigate` method, without it triggering autoscroll from source.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to accomplish exactly. The scroll from source happens when the caret is placed in the editor (if the editor is the selected editor) The code you are using to open the file is what your question is about, can we see that?

Comment: Well I'm opening a specific file from the project pane into the editor, but the editor then triggers autoscroll from source, shifting the selected row in the project pane - but I want to avoid this (without having to disable autoscrollfromsource). There must be some way to navigate to (open) the source file without triggering it.

Comment: If `navigate(false)` isn't enough. You can listen for `FileEditorManager` events, and stop the editor you open from becoming the selected editor.

Comment: Ok, this seems to be what I need (`FileEditorManagerEvent`) - can you please tell me where to register the listener? I couldn't see any `addFileEditorEventListener` style method on `FileEditorManager`...

Comment: Ok, I found it in `FileEditorManagerImpl`.

Comment: Alright, sylvanaar, I think I can now use these file editor manager events to detect when the file has been opened and re-enable autoscroll after that. I'm happy to accept this as an answer if you want to add it. Thanks - Steve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `navigate(false)` isn't enough. You can listen for `FileEditorManager` events, and stop the editor you open from becoming the selected editor.

Comment: Hi sylvanaar, I'm taking up this task again. Do you have any hints on this? I can't see how to procede.